# What is the derivative of $(\mathbf{u}(x))^TA\mathbf{v}(x)$ w.r.t. $x$?

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, matrix-calculus

What is $\frac{d}{dx}(\mathbf{u}^TA\mathbf{v})$ where $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ are column-vector-valued functions of $x$, and $A$ is a matrix?

Is it $\frac{d\mathbf{u}^T}{dx}A\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{u}^TA\frac{d\mathbf{v}}{dx}$?

Comment: Yes, it is.....

Comment: If $x$ is a scalar then you are right, but if $x$ is a **vector** then you must account for the matrix nature of the Jacobians, and the correct expression is 
$$
\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^TAv
\;+\;
\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right)^TA^Tu
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as @Hermis14 said, it's true.

**Notice:** it's based on hypothesis of "$A$ is a constant matrix".